# Java Modeling Language for C?

Tags: c, formal-methods

I remember reading something about a formal specification language for C a while ago, but I can not find it now that I need it.

It was inspired by JML, using as far as I saw the same syntax.

The only reference to it I found is a [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.119.9402%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=C%20modeling%20language&ei=W3esTMPeDsKRswb0mZXBBA&usg=AFQjCNGDXnsi0gYz1KNTSi13GiBsuKVp9Q&cad=rja), but what I am talking about was more polished than that.

If this rings a bell to you...

If nobody knows about this, I'll be happy to hear about a way to do formal verification and automatic test generation in C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with CML, but the article you link starts with the statement that it is for specification of non-functional requirements.

JML is for functional requirements of Java programs (okay, the line is blurry, but I think the CML article is using the word in the same sense as this sentence). An equivalent of JML for C programs (therefore also purely for functional requirements) is [ACSL](http://frama-c.com/acsl.html).

For formal verification, I can only recommend [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) (disclaimer: I work on Frama-C but not on a part that has to do with ACSL specifications). For test generation for C programs, I have heard good things about [CUTE](http://osl.cs.uiuc.edu/~ksen/cute/).

Answer (score 0):

Formal specification "for" C?

I know of work to formally *specify* C: [Denotational Semantics for C](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.3178).

If you want to specify *what* C programs do, then the [Property Specification Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_Specification_Language) might be a useful place to start.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 4 verification systems for C around:

1. Escher C Verifier. [I am connected with this.]
2. [Microsoft VCC](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/vcc/).
3. [Frama-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frama-C) with the Jessie plugin (available on Debian/Ubuntu in the package `frama-c`. You'll need to install `why` too to make jessie work)
4. [VeriFast](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.jacobs/verifast/).

(1) is intended for safety-critical embedded C programs written in MISRA-C or similar. 
(2) is intended for multithreaded systems built using the Microsoft C compilers.
I know rather less abiout (3) and (4).